# Merkle–Damgård padded block concatenated outside the compression function hash?

Tags: collision-resistance, merkle-damgaard

I learned that the output of hash function from Merkle Damgard is

`H(x) = ZB+1 = h(ZB || L) = h(ZB - 1 || XB || L) where XB = block of padded x and L = XB+1`

and it is proven that H(x) is collision resistant. 
However, what if I tweak the H(x) by extracting L from the compression function h(x) s.t

`H(x) = h(ZB - 1 || XB) || L`

I feel like this makes H(x) to be not collision resistant, but I don't know how to design an attack for this hash function. Can someone give me an idea (perhaps hint) to design such attack?

NOTE: *Before anyone screams at me about anything, I want to say YES this is a practice question from a cryptography textbook. That is why I asked for a HINT not an answer. Thanks :)*

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you look at it the other way; suppose you could find a collision with your modified `H(x) = h(ZB - 1 || XB) || L`; could you use that collision to find a collision in the original `H`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get it. I thought my newly modified H(x) needs to be compared with its h(x), instead of the original H, to prove whether it is collision resistant or not. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ThomasWest: if you prove that, if you can find a collision in the new $H$, you can find a collision in the original $H$, then you've proven that the new $H$ is at least as collision resistant as the original.

Comment: Can you give more hint? I recently thought that this case is actually a collision-resistant problem

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this too but would like to give it a try (as a test to my understanding). The compression function h(x) is collision resistance to start with, and length(L) << length(X), so the adversary can find a collision by brute force. However the same attack requires the adversary to brute force the whole message space X to find collision, hence the new H(x) is not as secure as the original Merkle Damgard scheme.

Comment: Interesting, I just thought that this problem might be a collision-resistant case.